# Django - Button that will change a field in a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a scrum application where there are Sprint and User Story objects. I want the user to be able to click a button on the Sprint detail template and for a BooleanField in the model to be changed from False to True, marking the Sprint as complete. I have tried to think but not sure how I can about this?

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

class Sprint(models.Model):
    LENGTH_CHOICES = (('1_week', '1 Week'), ('2_weeks', '2 Weeks'), ('3_weeks', '3 Weeks'))
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sprints", null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sprints", null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = LENGTH_CHOICES)
    complete = models.BooleanField(null = True, default = False)
    retrospective = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

class UserStory(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('To Do', 'To Do'),('In Progress', 'In Progress'), ('In Review', 'In Review'), ('Complete', 'Complete'))
    STORY_POINTS = ((0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (5, 5), (8, 8), (13, 13), (20, 20), (40, 40), (100, 100))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    sprint = models.ForeignKey(Sprint, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="userstories", null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 11, choices = STATUS_CHOICES, default = 'to do')
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="userstories", null=True)
    estimate = models.IntegerField(choices = STORY_POINTS, default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

If any further info is needed please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need a url and view that the button will be hooked up to.

urls.py:

```
  path('sprint/<int:pk>/complete', CompleteSprintView.as_view(), name='complete-sprint'),
```

views.py:

```
from django.views import View
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class CompleteSprintView(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Sprint, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

        obj.complete = not obj.complete
        obj.save()
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('<url name for sprint detail>', kwargs={'pk': obj.pk}))
```

template (where `sprint` is in the context):

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'complete-sprint' pk=sprint.pk %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit" title="Complete Sprint">Complete Sprint</button>
</form>
```